# Variance of AWGN in BFSK system

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, digital-communications

I am trying to compute the variance of AWGN in the system for finding the BER with $Q$ function.

The PSD of the AWGN is $N_0/2$, my answer was $N_0T$ but it was incorrect.

[image: BFSK system]

This is my calculation (incorrect):

[image]

Comment: Not quite sure what you're calculating here – usually, the variance of the noise has the *effect* of a BER. So, what is given here, and what are you trying to find?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Huh? _effect_ of a BER? What does that mean?  To my mind, what the OP is doing is perfectly correct, and I don't know why he is being told that his calculation is incorrect.  Unless his professor was wanting the noise variance at the input to the sampler and the professor was testing whether students knew enough to add the two variances thus computed even though the noise at the sampler input was the difference of the two branch noises.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think this was badly worded: "has the effect of a BER" is supposed to mean "having an SNR < $\infty$ results in a bit error rate" –